# Referencing a module component class in GridView

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm loading bootstrap into a module:

```
'modules'=>array(
    'admin'=>array(
        'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
        'components'=>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
                'responsiveCss' => true,
            ),
        )
    ),
),
```

in a GridView I'm trying to create a TbButtonColumn:

```
array(
    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
),
```

This returns a CException

> Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined.

as it points to a bootstrap in the main config app which obviously doesn't exist, how do I reference bootstrap when it is loaded in the module?

I tried:

> components.bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn
>
> admin.components.bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn
>
> admin.bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of culprit are in [TbGridView's `init()`](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/src/ee531ea4d03a7d7ca3930a2af647b327bd28e6de/widgets/TbGridView.php?at=default#cl-78):

```
$popover = Yii::app()->bootstrap->popoverSelector;
$tooltip = Yii::app()->bootstrap->tooltipSelector;
```

Changing them to this will help:

```
if (!($module=Yii::app()->controller->module)){// access as application component (original behavior)
    $popover = Yii::app()->bootstrap->popoverSelector;
    $tooltip = Yii::app()->bootstrap->tooltipSelector;
}
else {// access as module component 
    $popover = $module->bootstrap->popoverSelector;
    $tooltip = $module->bootstrap->tooltipSelector;
}
```

The same two lines are in `TbListView` also, so if you use `TbListView`, you can make the same changes.

---

Update: There already seems to be an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-bootstrap/issue/149/tbgridview-didnt-work-if-it-resides-in-yii) regarding this, solution posted there looks better:

```
$module = ( Yii::app()->controller->module ? Yii::app()->controller->module : Yii::app() );

$popover = $module->bootstrap->popoverSelector;
$tooltip = $module->bootstrap->tooltipSelector;
```